# gganimate: include additional variable other than states level variable or frame in title expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'd like to insert *another* column value of my data into a `gganimate` animation title.

Example, here the states level variable is `x` and I'd like to add to title variable `y`:

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', letters[1:5]))
df

A tibble: 10 x 2
       x y    
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 a    
 2     2 a    
 3     3 b    
 4     4 d    
 5     5 c    
 6     6 a    
 7     7 b    
 8     8 c    
 9     9 d    
10    10 e
```

This works as expected:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = '{closest_state}') +
  transition_states(x,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)
```

[image]

This fails:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = '{closest_state}, another_var: {y}') +
  transition_states(x,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)
```

> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) :
>   object 'y' not found

Also tried this, but `y` will not change:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = str_c('{closest_state}, another_var: ', df$y)) +
  transition_states(x,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)
```

[image]

Another option is to map `y` as the states level variable and use the `frame` variable instead of `x`, but in my application `y` is either a not-necessarily-unique character variable like above, or it is a numeric variable but again not-necessarily-unique and not-necessarily-ordered. In which case `gganimate` (or `ggplot`?) will order it as it sees fit, making the final result weird not ordered by `x`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = '{frame}, another_var: {closest_state}') +
  transition_states(y,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)
```

[image]

So how to simply add the changing value of the un-ordered, not numeric, `y` variable?

Finally: This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479557/custom-column-to-frame-title-in-gganimate) but without a reproducible example so it was not answered, hoping this one is better.

Comment: Good that you have done background study & formatted well. This helps in the comprehension & quick dispersal of knowledge.

Comment: What if you create a dedicated new variable to use in `transition_states`? Maybe this is not desired, so I'll use a comment and will delete if it's not what you intended, but: `df <- mutate(df, title_var = paste(x, y, sep="-"))` then `+
  transition_states(title_var,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)`

Comment: Great direction! However: 1. It doesn't work yet, `title_var` is a character vector sorted in the title like "1-a", "10-a", etc, not sorted by `x` ; 2. What if I didn't want `x` in the title? `y` is the important variable here, I think we should have a solution which lets you have that different variable in the title, in general.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't see any way to include another variable [in the doc](https://gganimate.com/reference/transition_states.html?q=label#label-variables) (other than what @RLave suggested).Maybe you should [open an issue on github](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/new)?

Comment: @RLave this fixes my (1) item: `df <- mutate(df, title_var = factor(paste(x, y, sep="-"), levels = paste(x, y, sep="-")))`, now `title_var` is a sorted factor and this is the best we have so far.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't be surprised if that's the best we can do at the moment, @7hibault I'll open that issue anyway.

Comment: issue submitted https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/252

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One dirty solution would be to `paste` together the variables and make a new one to use in the `transition_states`:

```
df <- mutate(df, title_var = factor(paste(x, y, sep="-"), levels = paste(x, y, sep="-")))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# x y     title_var
# <int> <chr> <fct>    
# 1     1 a     1-a      
# 2     2 a     2-a      
# 3     3 b     3-b      
# 4     4 d     4-d      
# 5     5 c     5-c      
# 6     6 a     6-a
```

Then we could use `gsub()` in ordet to strip `closest_state` from the unwanted part, like this:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\d+-", replacement = "", "1-a") 
"a"
```

So:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = '{gsub(pattern = "\\d+-", replacement = "", closest_state)}') +
  transition_states(title_var, transition_length = 0.1, state_length = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Look again, they are not ordered properly without `df <- mutate(df, title_var = factor(paste(x, y, sep="-"), levels = paste(x, y, sep="-")))`.

Comment: This works: `labs(title = '{gsub(pattern = "[0-9]+-", replacement = "", closest_state)}')`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, slightly more compact, from the author of `gganimate` himself, following the issue I opened:

https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/252#issuecomment-450846868

According to Thomas:

> There are multiple reasons why random columns from the input data
>   cannot be accessed so it is unlikely to get any better than this...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`, based on the `gganimate` developer Thomas's solution, provided by Giora.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

df <- tibble::tibble(x = 1:10, y = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', letters[1:5]))

a <- ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "{closest_state}, another_var: {df %>% filter(x == closest_state) %>% pull(y)}") +
  transition_states(x,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 0.1)
animate(a)
```

The `gganimate` titles use `glue` syntax for the animated title elements, and you can include entire `dplyr` data manipulation pipelines within them.

You can refer to the `closest_state` variable provided by `gganimate::transition_states()` within your `dplyr` calls. Here, since the animation's frames are indexed by successive levels of `x`, I use `filter()` to subset `df` for a given frame based on the value of `x` and then refer to corresponding rows of column `y`, which contain additional information I'd like to display in the title. Using `pull`, you can grab the individual value of `y` corresponding to `x` and display it within the animation's title.

This is a clean and straightforward way to do it with the advantage that you can, e.g., compute summary values to display on-the-fly by adding `summarize()` and other calls in your `magrittr` pipeline.