# How to use custom string instead of frame number in gganimate {frame}?

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, frame, gganimate

In this example if you run you get a nice standard animation which has been used a lot. Also, showing at the top "Frame n of N". 
But what if you want it simply to say something in a string? 
e.g. have it read Str <- c('A', 'B', 'C',...)
Obviously you would have to make sure the string length matches the number of frames. Is this possible?

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point()
p

anim <- p + transition_states(Species,
                      transition_length = 2,
                      state_length = 1)  

anim + ggtitle('Frame {frame} of {nframes}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point()
anim <- p + transition_states(Species,
                              transition_length = 2,
                              state_length = 1) +
  labs(title = 'Title : {closest_state}')
anim
```

Comment: I don't think so. It's too restricted. I simply want a customisable string. There are 150 frames so let's say str <- c("A", "B", "C", ... , "ES", "ET"). That would be 150 characters that would go over each frame.

Comment: i get you, i think the closest thing is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864892/gganimate-include-additional-variable-other-than-states-level-variable-or-frame

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for! I have to go for a while so will double check later. Thanks!